# How do I use an arbitrary HTTP verb in a ServiceStack REST service?

Tags: rest, servicestack

When using ServiceStack to create a REST service, how do you handle arbitrary HTTP verbs?

The most common verbs have very simple methods.  For example, to handle a GET request I would do the following:

```csharp
public class MyService : RestServiceBase<MyRequest>
{
    public override object OnGet(MyRequest request){
        //do stuff and return HttpResult or object for serialization
    }
}
```

Similar overrides exist for PUT, POST, DELETE, and PATCH.

What do I do if I want to use HEAD or some other verb?

(I've looked through the documentation and examples and [other ServiceStack questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/servicestack) but haven't found anything that indicates the correct way to do this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServiceStack's [RestServiceBase](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/RestServiceBase.cs) class already has built-in support for GET, POST, PUSH, DELETE and PATCH. so you just override it as you would your `OnGet()` method, e.g. you can handle DELETE requests with:

```
public override object OnDelete(MyRequest request){
    //do stuff and return HttpResult or object for serialization
}
```

For HEAD requests you currently can't handle this in a ServiceStack service so you will need to handle it in either a [RequestFilter](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Request-and-response-filters) or [RequestFitler Attribute](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Filter-attributes) (make sure you close the httpRes to terminate the request).

You also have the opportunity to by-pass the ServiceStack pipeline completely by registering your own Custom IHttpHandler in the [EndpointHostConfig.RawHttpHandlers](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/WebHost.EndPoints/EndpointHostConfig.cs#L362) config in your AppHost.

Comment: Thanks.  Played around with the RequestFilter option but was hoping for a cleaner way.  Any plans to implement a HEAD handler in the future?

Comment: The only problem with that is that the HEAD response shouldn't have a body, in which case your response will get discarded, the only valid return type would be a `IHttpResult` so it can write any custom headers that were set, and ignore the response. We'll look at adding some support here...